# Can I ask HR to let me skip two more interviews and offer me a job directly?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, recruitment, human-resources, negotiation

I had 2 job interviews lately (one in late July and one in mid August). After the 2nd interview I got a rejection email but the HR (technical recruiter) told me the team (team A) I had interviews with still thinks I am a strong candidate and would like to reach back to me when a new position opens up. I relied with thank you and told her I would be very interested (I really want to work for this company).

Just after about 1 week after I received the rejection, the same HR reached back to me with a similar position in another division (team B). I said yes and had the third interview just today.

---

But here is the thing I don't understand and feel exhausted about: the interviewers who interviewed me today are the team leads (division head as the title) from team A. Prior to today's interview, I thought if I could pass this one, I would get the job from division B. But during today's interview I was told I had 2 more interviews to go through with the team members from division B.

It's been literally 2.5 months since I was first in contact with the company and now I'm really exhausted with the lengthy recruitment process and 2 more interviews ahead with another team. If I got a pass email from the HR for today's interview later next week (I did well today and I feel the heads from team A really like me), can I ask her if she could find me any position within team A and just let me work for division A? I know this seems inappropriate but I don't like to restart the recruitment process again with team B. Here are a few things I am considering:

1. It takes at most 3 interviews to get a job at this company. The last one is usually with the team manager. If today's interviewers (they are the lead of team A) approved of my ability, why can't they provide me with a position in their team? I mean even I got rejected by the interviewers of my 2nd interview, they said they still like me and they are also not manager-level within team A, basically I will get 3 yes from team A if I passed today's interview.
2. Seriously, it makes it tough for me to handle other job opportunities (although this is by far my most interested company).

---

In short, if I get a pass email for today's interview, what can I say to let the HR know my situation and bargain with them, preferably asking her to just offer me a job within division A (like find/create another open position) or just let me skip the 2 interviews for the position at division B (which I think has less chance)?

Comment: If you make either of those demands, I doubt you will ever be able to work at that company.

Comment: What would expediting the process look like to you?  It sounds like the first two interviews were a couple weeks apart and most of the 2.5 months since first contact was during the time that you were eliminated from the running for the first position and before the second position became available.  The actual interview process seems to have moved reasonably quickly.

Comment: (although this is by far my most interested company)   >> Then you had better do as they ask.

Comment: It would make sense to skip the HR interviews, but not make sense for the interviews with the team leads. The exception would be if the team leaders trusted each other, and the work was similar for both teams.

Comment: I would follow the process.  If you don’t think team b us a good fit then let HR know that this is not the right opportunity for you but you still are interested in Team A.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> why can't they provide me with a position in [team A]?

Maybe they don't have any (relevant) open positions right now.

> just let me skip the 2 interviews for the position at division B

Consider this from the other side - would you ever want somebody coming into your team who you hadn't interviewed? If somebody tried to do that to my team, my boss would know how I felt about it in no uncertain terms. You can't assume that just because you passed some interviews with Team A, you'd also pass them with Team B - maybe they have a different technical focus, maybe their team culture is different and you wouldn't fit in.

Or in other words: you can ask. But expect the answer to be "no", and if I'm being honest I'd regard a candidate asking this as a bad sign as it shows they're not very aware of the issues involved.

Comment: You can ask or even demand anything you want, but you need to be in a very strong negotiating position if you want them to skip their processes with a high chance of success. It happens fairly often in highly skilled positions in low human resource areas. OP doesn't seem to have that sort of power though on the info given

Comment: @Nicholas What, exactly, does "expedite" mean to you in this situation? Skip steps, or go through the steps more quickly? Do you have any leverage here, or are you hoping that the HR office will do you a favor?

Comment: Further to Philip's comment about the team wanting to meet you before deciding: wouldn't **you** want to meet your potential coworkers before deciding to change jobs? What if you don't like them? Might as well find that out before making your decision.